# Why can't I open a shell from a pipelined process?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I've condensed my problem into the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Enter input: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    system("/bin/sh");
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this program with user input, I get:

```
user@ubuntu:~/testing/temp$ ./main
Enter input: Test
$
```

With the last line being the shell that the program started.

But if I run the program with input coming from the pipeline:

```
user@ubuntu:~/testing/temp$ echo 'test' | ./main
Enter input: user@ubuntu:~/testing/temp$
```

The program doesn't seem to open the shell.

---

After some tinkering, I realized that if I did this:

```
user@ubuntu:~/testing/temp$ (python -c "print 'test'" ; echo 'ls') | ./main
a.out  main  main.c
Enter input: user@ubuntu:~/testing/temp
```

I was able to run the `ls` command in the opened shell.

So, two questions:

1. Why doesn't the shell open like it did in the first case?
2. How can I deal with this? It's very inconvenient to have to decide what commands to run *before* running the program: I'd much rather have a shell where I can dynamically choose what commands to run.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: This question is better suited for stack overflow.

Comment: @bahamat: Is it?  As far as I can tell the question is about UNIX, not about programming.

Comment: "How can I deal with this" in C, is probably going to have better luck on stackoverflow, as evidenced by the two answers that explain why, but not how to deal with it.

Comment: @bahamat: I'd say that's because it isn't clear what the OP means by "dealing with it". _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047: I think it's pretty clear he means "how do I make the shell interactive?". And I think that people with more experience with C can answer that better.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I didn't down vote. I *did* vote to close and move to http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @bahamat: "How to make the shell interactive if `stdin` is a pipe"? The answer is to use a `pty(7)`.  No programming involved (not in the answer that is). ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23707/discussion-between-bahamat-and-lcd047).

Comment: @lcd047 Can you expand on your `pty` comment?

Comment: @Daniel: Not really, sorry.  If you aren't familiar with `pty`s, you won't understand them to a satisfactory degree from SE.  I can recommend you a book though.

Comment: @lcd047 I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Daniel: R. Stevens - [Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/).  It's a really good book, you won't regret any minute you spend reading it.

Comment: Oooh! someone who's read 'the good book' :)

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why doesn't the shell open like it did in the first case?

In the first case, `stdin` is a terminal and the shell is interactive.  It waits for your commands etc.

In the second case `stdin` is a pipe, and the shell is non-interactive.  Your program consumes the first line on `stdin` (namely the string `test\n`), then the shell tries to read `stdin` and sees `EOF`.  It exits, because that's what programs that get `EOF` on input are supposed to do.

In the third case the shell again is non-interactive, for the same reason.  Your `scanf()` consumes the first line on `stdin` (i.e. `test\n`), then the shell reads `ls`.  The shell runs `ls`, tries to read more commands, sees `EOF`, and exits.

> 2. How can I deal with this?

If by "dealing with it" you mean running an interactive shell when `stdin` is connected to a pipe, the solution is to use a `pty(7)`.

Comment: Dealing with it means between the `scanf` and the `system`, closing STDIN and reopening it to the /dev/pty. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your C program will behave very similarly to `(read x; /bin/sh)`.

If you just type this snipped on a command line, then its standard
input is connected to your terminal's keyboard; a line will be read,
and then `sh` will read more lines until an end-of-file condition
occurs (typically, one can hit Ctrl-D to cause one).

In the example where you pipe into your program, the input size is
bounded; it's what you put there and nothing more: the lines after the
first one, if any, will be interpreted by `sh`, which will then exit.

You could kindof simulate the pipe-less case by using cat to forward
your keyboard input to `sh`:

```
(echo test; cat) | (read x; /bin/sh)
```

or perhaps:

```
(echo test; cat) | ./main
```

That probably won't be as nice as running a shell directly, however;
detecting that its input isn't a terminal, it will probably disable
its line editing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To run an interactive shell connected to a pipe, you just have to make it interactive.

```
input | /bin/sh -i
```

The shell doesn't need a terminal to be interactive - it needs interactive input. In the main, the shell's behavior when run interactively has very little to do with terminals at all - *(at least according to [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html))* - and generally differs from a non-interactive shell's behavior where error handling is concerned more than anything else. Interactive shells tend not to exit on error conditions that would otherwise cause a non-interactive shell to quit. A shell should *default* to interactive-mode if input comes from a terminal, though.

Some shells may seem to require terminal input for interactive use, but this is an illusion. In fact, these shells typically work very like your example case under the hood - `bash`, for example, sets up `readline` to handle the terminal i/o nitty-gritty on its behalf, `zsh` invokes its ZLE line-editor, and `dash` *(if not compiled with the build-time option **SMALL**)* links in BSD's `libedit` library. These line-editors read and process the terminal input into something like a line-by-line shell-script, which the shell then executes as appropriate.

You're not having an issue with any of those editors, though. Judging by your prompt and your execve call, you're calling up a `dash` that is compiled with the *SMALL* build-time option *(the Debian default)* in which case it will just work - but the only line-editing functions you might get out of it will be those natively provided by the terminal's line-discipline *(see [`stty`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty))*.

Your problem is that the shell doesn't have any input - when it detects EOF it dies as has already been noted elsewhere. You might do...

```
input | /bin/sh -i -o ignoreeof
```

But you will probably *not* like the results. `dash` won't do the quit on 10th consecutive null-read thing that some shells do - it will just print...

```
Type 'exit' to exit the shell
```

...to stderr *forever*. A little better could be...

```
cat input - | /bin/sh -i
```

...to concactenate the shell commands in the `input` file with `cat`'s `-` stdin to its stdout and then to execute the results in an interactive `/bin/sh`. This will work - though you may want to ensure you configure the `stty` line-discipline to something like a canonical-state and with an appropriate `erase` key so you can at least get a functioning backspace. This is probably already set correctly - but it's worth checking anyway.

Another way...

```
echo ": some command; exec <$(tty)" | /bin/sh -i
```

The above methods will work because your pipeline is the current foreground job on the controlling terminal - your pipeline currently owns the terminal input and `cat` is actually reading it. This is contrasted by `python -c` and `echo` which do not read it - they only pass-on output as generated by command-line arguments - and so when their output ends so also does your shell's input. This is true unless the shell is instructed to look for input elsewhere as I do with `echo` in the second example.

The terminal is just one possible source of input of many to a shell - and it can be handled in many different ways. Your terminal's session leader - it looks like `bash` - waits for your pipeline's terminal control to end so it can regain control and do the next thing. This information will be passed to it as an asynchronous signal - this is what terminals are for. Terminals multiplex a display/input pair across any number of reading/printing processes. They do this very well.

For example:

```
$ PS1='bgsh1: ' sh -i +m & PS1='bgsh2: ' sh -i +m &
$ bgsh1: bgsh2: 
[2] + Stopped (tty input)        sh -i +m
[1] - Stopped (tty input)        sh -i +m
$ i=0; while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt 5 ]; do fg "%$(((i%2)+1))"; done
sh -i +m

bgsh2: var=something
bgsh2: kill -TSTP $$
sh -i +m

bgsh1: var=else
bgsh1: kill -TSTP $$
sh -i +m
bgsh2: echo $var; kill -TSTP $$
something
sh -i +m
bgsh1: echo $var; kill -TSTP $$
else
[1] + Stopped                    sh -i +m
[2] - Stopped                    sh -i +m
$
```